# What does the "3" in printf(3) denote?

Tags: c, manpage

`man` pages of the `printf` and online documentations often show `printf(3)` when explaining the functionality of `printf`. What does the "3" denote?

Comment: It’s a section! See `man man`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `man` about the `man` page. 3 referers to Library calls.So 'printf(3)' is a library call.

Answer (score 1):

`3` denotes the section which `printf` is a part of. Section `3` corresponds to: Library calls (functions within program libraries).

You could also issue `man <section number> <keyword>`, eg. `man 3 printf` to look up a keyword in a specific section. `man 1 printf` will show you the `printf` shell command.

Answer (score 0):

Your `printf`  is a library function so documented in [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html). See [intro(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/intro.3.html) but there is a similar command [printf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/printf.1.html)

And see [man-pages(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/man-pages.7.html) for organization of `man` pages